# Calculate AUC for test set (keras model in R)

Tags: r, keras

Is there a way (function) to calculate AUC value for a keras model in R on test-set?
I have searched on google but nothing shown up.
From Keras model, we can extract the predicted values as either class or probability as follows:
Probability:

```
 [1,] 9.913518e-01 1.087829e-02
  [2,] 9.990101e-01 1.216531e-03
  [3,] 9.445553e-01 6.256607e-02
  [4,] 9.928864e-01 6.808311e-03
  [5,] 9.993126e-01 1.028240e-03
  [6,] 6.075442e-01 3.926141e-01
```

Class:

```
1                                   0
2                                   0
3                                   0
4                                   0
5                                   0
6                                   0
7                                   0
8                                   0
```

Many thanks,
Ho

Answer (score 1):

Generally it does not really matter what calssifier (keras or not) did the prediction. All you need to estimate the AUC are two things: the predicted probabilities from some classifier and the actual category (for example, dead "yes" vs. "no"). With this data you can calculate both, True Positive Rate and False positive rate, thus you can also make a ROC plot and estimate AUC with this data.  You can use

```
library(pROC)
roc_obj <- roc(category, prediction)
auc(roc_obj)
```

See [here](https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2016/11/calculating-auc.html) for some more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will answer your needs as it depends on your data structure and `keras` output format, but have a look to Dismo package's function `evaluate`. You need to set up something like that:

```
library(dismo)
predictors <- stack of explaining variables
pres_test <- a subset of data used to model ##that you not use in your model for this testing purpose
backg_test <- true or random (background) absence data
model <- output of your model
AUC <- evaluate(pres_test, backg_test, model, predictors) ## you may bootstrap this step x time by randomly selecting 'pres_test' and 'backg_test' x time.
```

Comment: I edited my question to include the outputs that I can get from a keras model, please can you have a look. I am now also trying to look at the dismo package to see if it can be used. Thanks

Comment: Looking at your output (Probability) it seems that yes you could use dismo evaluate function to calculate AUC.